# MySQL Query for Row with Most Recent Date

Tags: mysql, sql, database, date, timestamp

Let's say I have a table called "signup_info" as follows:

```
p_key_id    name    gender    signup_date
1           Bob     male      10/5/17
2           Mary    female    9/23/14
3           Jamie   female    2/6/15
4           Jamie   male      3/22/17
```

How would I write a query that would only give me the most row pertaining to the most recent signup_date for every instance of a person's name?

Comment: Is `signup_date` a `DATE` or a `VARCHAR`?  It looks like a `VARCHAR`...

Answer (score 2):

I would use a correlated subquery:

```
select si.*
from signup_info si
where si.signup_date = (select max(s2.signup_date) from signup_info si2 where si2.name = si.name);
```

If `p_key_id` is autoincrementing, then it might provide a more reliable way to get the most recent:

```
select si.*
from signup_info si
where si.p_key_id = (select max(s2.p_key_id) from signup_info si2 where si2.name = si.name);
```

If someone signs up twice on the same date, then the first will return duplicate rows for that person.